# JSON image data is not as expected

Tags: json, swift, image, uiimage

In the server I have a byte array of an image. The data I receive from my JSON request is not same as the data on the server. Instead of a byte array of an image, I get some strange string.

This is my code:

```
Alamofire.request(mainUrl, method:.post , parameters: paramstring , encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { response in
    if let data = response.data
    {
        switch response.result
        {
        case.failure(let error):
            print(error)
        case.success(let value):
            let json = JSON(value)
            guard let dataarr = json["my_profile"].arrayObject as? [String] else {return}
            var imagebyte = dataarr[0] // here I should get byte array of image
            let data = Data(bytes: imagebyte) // convert byte array to data
            self.MainView.avatarImageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: JSON won't contain binary data, it's most like encoded into a textual representation, such as Base64. You will need to decode the `String` back to a binary value

Comment: Update your question with the initial portion (say about 50 characters) of the value of `imagebyte`.

Comment: can you print your JSON

Comment: This is a small part of json , I think he return to me code of image "my_profile": [
    "\\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

Comment: imagebyte: this saved in the server like byte array , which I should convert after to image . When I'm get response data of image (byte array) , their get to me unknown string , I'm try to convert it , but he return to me different byte array , not same with which saved on the server